# How can I remotely log someone off from my Google (Chrome) account?

Tags: google-chrome, logoff

I have a friend who used to use Safari and (about a year ago) I used to use Google Chrome on her laptop because I didn't have my own at the time.

I completely forgot that it was even syncing the entire time, until today I saw that she's surfing from my account. :P

How can I log her off my account?

Comment: Settings - Disconnect your Google Account.

Comment: I am not by her laptop. I am asking her to do it. I hope she doesn't mind it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Google account password to something she doesn't know.

It won't cause her to become logged off, but should prevent her from logging back into it next time she opens Chrome.